# How to reduce faces of quad mesh

Tags: mesh, faces

I have converted a tri-mesh to quad-mesh and now need to reduce the number of mesh faces.  Currently 125,000 faces and need to be under 50,000 faces.  Any help?

I'm not going to share the file since it is someone else intellectual property that they sell.

It is a tri-mesh STL of a nurse wearing boxing glove and wearing a mask. The final use will primarily to be gifts for first line nurses. I'm retired and 70 years old, so no business intention on this file.

My end goal is to convert it into a solid in Autodesk Fusion 360 for subtractive machining.  Fusion can only convert quad mesh into a solid.  Fusion will only do that for models with less than 50,000 faces.

After posting the question I found a YouTube on using *Decimate* in Blender and tried it. Chose modifier, decimate, un-subdivide like the YouTube. Changed the iteration to 1 and it reduced it to 975,000 faces, iteration to 2 only lowered it to 965,000 and iteration 3 to 958,000.  There was promise at first iteration, but lost promise as time went on.  I couldn't find a way to enter a value in iteration, just the arrow to increase single digit at a time.

I have Carveco Maker, which didn't do the heavy lifting. I've tried Autodesk Meshmixer and Netfabb without the result I want. I had Meshcam, but a hard drive crash wiped it out and no help from Meshcam since another revision had been released.

Comment: In order of preference, IMO: manual retopology, quad remesher (paid addon), instamesh addon/3rd party app, native blender remeshing tools, decimate modifier.

Comment: Well, what is it? A building, or a dragon? You can always use the decimate or simplify tools, but IDK if this will help or tremendously hurt you.

Comment: Hello, please give more informations about the kind of object, how your topology looks like, etc, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/